# Flutter bloc - Getting data from DB asynchronously

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am making an app using the BLoC architecture using the `flutter_bloc` package, but I need to get data from a database, which is asynchronous, meaning I can't initialize the BLoC with data from my database. Is there a way I can do this? My BLoC class text is

```dart
import 'package:countdown/database/utils.dart';
import 'package:countdown/events/countdown_event.dart';
import 'package:countdown/models/countdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class HomeBloc extends Bloc<CountdownEvent, List<Countdown>> {
   @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  List<Countdown> get initialState => DatabaseUtils.getCountdowns();


  @override
  Stream<List<Countdown>> mapEventToState(CountdownEvent event) {
  }
}
```

I know this is very similar to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370304/flutter-bloc-make-initialstate-method-async), but that question's answers don't have any code snippets which would be very helpful.

Comment: create one separate async function and call if from initState().

Comment: initState() would still have to return a Future, which makes it an invalid override of the parent class.

Comment: *" but I need to get data from a database, which is asynchronous,"* - so you need to read [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) amd [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

Comment: The initialState has to be an instance of the type parameter State, which in my case is a List

Comment: and whats wrong with `[]` in that case?

Comment: I would like for the initial state of the BLoC to be the data in the DB, so an empty list would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one separate async function and call if from initState(). this is my code you can call your method according to use.

```
  @override
  HomeState get initialState {
    _checkLocationSettings();
    return InitialHomeState();
  }



_checkLocationSettings() async {
locationUpdateSetting = await repository.isLocationUpdateOn();}
```